# QuestDB: How to configure memory usage?

Tags: questdb

I'm going to use QuestDB as an embedded database.
But what I found is pretty high memory usage after startup(No queries were performed).

If there is some sort of startup cache how it can be tuned?
Any config options?

Comment: There are many options which you can take advantage of and fine tune the DB. Can you please share more details, because with the provided info it's hard to give a specific answer.